# Drupal - How to get term Id from name with taxonomy_get_term_by_name

Tags: php, arrays, drupal, drupal-taxonomy

I have tried to use the following code to get a termId from a term:

```
  $term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($address_string); 
  $termId = $term[0]->tid;
```

There is 1 result, but it is appearing as term[30] - so the above code doesn't work.

I thought I could access the term array by looking at the first element - e.g. $term[0]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the result of var_dump($term):

---

```
array (size=1)
  30 => 
    object(stdClass)[270]
      public 'tid' => string '30' (length=2)
      public 'vid' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Thonglor' (length=8)
      public 'description' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'format' => string 'filtered_html' (length=13)
      public 'weight' => string '0' (length=1)
      public 'vocabulary_machine_name' => string 'areas' (length=5)
```

Many thanks,

PW

Comment: It works correctly. Your term has id = 30 in the database.

Comment: `array_shift()` is your friend here

Answer (score 6):

Probably the best option would be

```
$termid = key($term);
```

It will output **30**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php

> The key() function simply returns the key of the array element that's
>   currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move
>   the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end
>   of the elements list or the array is empty, key() returns NULL.

May be better to call

```
reset($term);
```

before calling the key function

**Reset** reset the internal array pointer to the first element

Other option is as Drupal API manual says itself,
https://api.drupal.org/comment/18909#comment-18909

```
/**
 * Helper function to dynamically get the tid from the term_name
 *
 * @param $term_name Term name
 * @param $vocabulary_name Name of the vocabulary to search the term in
 *
 * @return Term id of the found term or else FALSE
 */
function _get_term_from_name($term_name, $vocabulary_name) {
  if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary_name)) {
    $tree = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid);
    foreach ($tree as $term) {
      if ($term->name == $term_name) {
        return $term->tid;
      }
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use:                                     $inner = reset($term); $termId = $inner->tid;